# Android Storing Polygon and LongLat values between activites

Tags: android, android-intent, sharedpreferences, state

I am trying to create an android App which has 3 activities. The main screen contains a summary of information (static text currently) and one of the navigation links goes to a Map Activity.

When I navigate back to the main menu and them back to the map it clears the Polygon from the map and also loses the route that the user had followed previously. This is because when the map activity is navigated to again it calls the create method again which initialised these values.

Should I can initialising these somewhere else, or is it expected that I save them in SharedPreferences / Intents whenever the user navigates away from this activity, and re-load them when the create method is called again?

Initially I am looking to persisting the following objects, it would be nice if I could have a custom class to hold all the user geo data and just load that when going back to the map.

```
private ArrayList<LatLng> routePoints;
Polygon geoFencePolygon;
```

I have read several articles but I'm new to Android development so unsure on which approach is suitable to storing data like this as I want to ensure I'm doing things correctly.

Eventually I need to keep the location tracking running even when they navigate to anywhere within the app but I am learning the basics first :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are working on some geofancing or gps tracking application
and you want to keep running your location tracking or some process even he is not on map activity
and also you want to store your data at temporary location

I think you should use android services that starts with your first activity to track your location and store it
some where. so when you reach to your map activity you can have your all location data at a time.

i will sugest to use SQLITE to store your location insted of shared preferences
you can drop table when you dont need that location data any more

Comment: Should this be done realtime? I was hoping I could keep the details in state until the user stops the journey but is best practise to just maintain all the details in SQLITE or similar then? If so I will look into this now. I have the location tracking working but it's not on the main activity, should this be moved to a service then to ensure it keeps logging location when moving between activites or if the app is minimised?

Comment: Yes GPS things should be done in services and it should be stored in sqlite if you want loging your gps. and if it is tracking app than i sugest you should track also while it is minimized. means you should not stop your service until your app do not need to track

Comment: Would you say this is ideal for a Service or IntentService? It seems that I wouldn't want the main thread to be blocked by this running. How do I pass data from the service back to another other activities that require it? Writing to SQL and then reading back seems a bit clunky so I'm guessing there is a better approach for the app to refresh the route, whilst storing it afterwards in SQL?

Comment: do you want to store your routs dyuring all over application time even he is on other activity? if yes then i think best place is sqlite not shared preference. i will say service will be the best.